# MySQL : Legacy database constraint issues

Tags: mysql

I was given the task migrating a legacy database to MySQL and properly create associations. So, what I've done is import all the data into the database by setting `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`.

Now, however, I am having issues since it appears that there are numerous foreign key constraint issues.

THe application using the database only complains about contraint issues but not where they are. So, I am wondering how to go about finding these issues. Is there a self check that MySQL comes with? Or any other help finding these issues is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to ask the dbms which key columns in the referencing table have values that aren't in the referenced table.

```
create table a (
id integer primary key
);

create table b (
id integer primary key
);

insert into a values (1);
insert into a values (2);
insert into a values (3);

insert into b values (1);
insert into b values (2);
insert into b values (7);
```

Imagine that there should be a foreign key from b to a. Trying to add a foreign key to table b should fail, because '7' isn't in table a.  This query will return all the ids in b that aren't in a.

```
select b.id
from b
left join a on (a.id = b.id)
where a.id is null
```